# How to prevent my dialog opening more than once?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a data grids within two tabs. so when second tab click it should open a filter window (not a `<popup>`, its a `<window>`) . I am doing it as follows.

```
if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 1)  {      
     DashboardFilterView filterWindow = new DashboardFilterView();   
     filterWindow.ShowDialog();  }
```

When I click the close button of window it is closed.

**Question** :

After closing popup window, if I click on row of datagrid which is in my current tab, again popup window is displayed.

How can I prevent this from happening more than once?

Comment: What you actually want to do?Second time you don't want to open a popup window?

Comment: How do you handle tab click?

Comment: on grid row click i do not need to open the popup window again, it is a separate action, and also there is a strange behavior, this will happen only when first time click on grid row, after that clicking on grid row behave as usual.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but maybe if had a boolean with default value of true. When you click and value is true, you pop up your window and set value to false. When you change tabs, you set the value back to true again. Personally I would review what you are trying to do and redesign your interface instead of using such logic.

Comment: Where are you calling that code? In a mouse event handler of the TabControl?

Comment: within the `tabControl1_SelectionChanged` event

Comment: I found the reason to display popup again, `tabControl1_SelectionChanged ` event is fired when I click on grid row. can you please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Easy.  Don't use a popup.  The design seems awkward and annoying to me as a user, anyhow.  Imagine a filter you can only use ONCE.  What happens when I want to change my filter?  I have to restart the application?  Feh.

Comment: There is a separate filter button in tab control also, this is for first time loading, anyway we have to deliver what our client wants :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `tabControl1_SelectionChanged` event is firing for even grid row click, I added a check to confirm whether this event occurs from tab.

`e.OriginalSource is TabControl` solved the problem.

```
 private void tabControl1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OriginalSource is TabControl)
            {
                if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    // Do something               
                }
                else if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {  
                    DashboardFilterView filterWindow = new DashboardFilterView();
                    filterWindow.ShowDialog();         
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Just for curiosity. What is passed as `e.OriginalSource` on grid row click?

Comment: When grid row click `e.OriginalSource` is `DataGrid`

Comment: Your answer presents a good workaround for routed event. I guess another solution is to handle `DataGrid.SelectionChanged` and set it to handled, but it's an overkill if you have multiple controls firing this event.